# Why do I get different results when using a function versus a macro?

Tags: c, function, macros, c-preprocessor

I'm using DevCPP IDE and I found that while programming in c,

Value returned by:

```
float f(float x)
{
      return 1/(1+x*x);
}
```

and value returned by f(x) if it's defined as:

```
#define f(x) 1/(1+x*x)
```

are different.

Why am I getting different results in these cases?

*EDIT:*

Here's my code for which I'm getting the anomaly:

```
main()    
{
      int i;

      float a=0, b=1, h, n=12, s1, s2=0;

      h=(b-a)/n; //step length

      s1=f(a)+f(b);

      for(i=1;i<=n-1;i++)

      {

        s2+=f(a+(i*h));

      }

      s1=(s1+2*s2)*h/2;

      printf("sum: %f", s1);   

      getch();
}
```

> OUTPUT 1: 0.693581 (using MACRO)
>
> OUTPUT 2: 0.785109 (using function)

Comment: How are you testing them? If they happen to be integers, the second will return 0 for any `x` except 0. The second will also perform side effects twice, and may have errors from text replacement.

Comment: Behold the difference between float and double.  Could be *char* with that gawdawful macro.

Comment: We cannot tell without seeing the calls.

Comment: Please reduce your code to a [mcve]. If you do that,I bet you will find the answer yourself.

Answer (score 3):

There are *many* possibilities here. Here's a few.

In the function version, the argument is explicitly typed as a `float`. This means that if you call

```
f(1);
```

then `1` is converted to the float `1.0f` as the argument. Then, when `1 / (1 + x * x)` is computed, it evaluates to `1 / 2.0f`, which comes out to `0.5f`. However, in the macro version, `f(1)` would be evaluated as `1 / 2` using integer division, yielding the value 0.

Second, in the function version, the argument is evaluated only once. This means that

```
int x = 0;
f(x++);
```

will increment `x` to `1`, then pass in the value `0`. The result will then be `1.0f`. In the macro version, however, the code expands to

```
1 / (1 + x++ * x++)
```

This causes has *undefined behavior* because there is no sequence point between the evaluations of `x++`. This expression could evaluate to *anything*, or it could crash the program outright.

Finally, the function version respects operator precedence while the macro does not. For example, in the function version, calling

```
f(1 - 1)
```

will call `f(0)`, evaluating to `1.0f`. In the macro version, this expands to

```
  1 / (1 + 1 - 1 * 1 - 1)
= 1 / (1 + 1 - 1 - 1)
= 1 / 0
```

This causes undefined behavior because of a divide-by-zero error.

The simple way to avoid this is to *not use macros to define functions*. Way back in the Bad Old Days this was a standard practice, but now that C has `inline` functions and compilers are way smarter, you should prefer functions to macros. They're safer, easier to use, and harder to mess up. They're also type aware and don't evaluate arguments multiple times.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yeah functions have loads of advantages over macros. But still out of curiosity, let the call be: f(1.34).. then what will be the logic if I use macro?

Comment: @BiswajitPaul- Try expanding it out yourself. What do you get?

Answer (score 1):

```
#define f(x) 1/(1+x*x)
```

should be defined as

```
#define f(x) 1/(1+(x)*(x))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#define f(x) (1/(1+x*x))
```

A `#define` basically sticks the code where the `#define`'d name was, so order of operations and precedence will apply.

Comment: Actually, for `f(1.0f + 1.0f)` for instance this would still go wrong.