# Macro and similar function return different results

Tags: c

I'm quite confusing about this:

```
    #define prod(x,y) x*y
```

The following function call prints `11` in the console:

```
    printf("%d",prod(1+2,3+4));
```

But when I use `prod(x,y)` as a function returning `x*y`, it returns 21.
Why the results are different? I thought `#define` should give `prod(x,y) = x*y`.

Comment: simple math. `1+2*3+4` is 11. Defines are not functions, they're simple text-replacement.

Comment: Every half-decent C book will have an example like this, with an explanation why it isn't working and how to fix it with parenthesis.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do I get different results when using a function versus a macro?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20182897/why-do-i-get-different-results-when-using-a-function-versus-a-macro)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Operator precedence is biting you.

With

```
#define prod(x,y) x*y
```

the line

```
printf("%d",prod(1+2,3+4));
```

gets expanded to

```
printf("%d",1+2*3+4);
```

Note that `*` has higher precedence than `+`, so this is evaluated as `1 + (2 * 3) + 4` or `11`.

**Solution:**

Surrround the parameters with parenthesis in your `#define`:

```
#define prod(x,y) ((x)*(y))
```

The line will now be expanded to:

```
printf("%d",((1+2)*(3+4)));
```

The purpose of the extra set of parenthesis around the entire expression is to make the expression work as you want when used in conjunction with an operator where evaluation order matters.

`prod(4,3)/prod(1,2))` gets expanded to `((4)*(3))/((1)*(2))` or `6`. Without the outer parenthesis the expansion would be `(4)*(3)/(1)*(2)` or `24`.

Answer (score 1):

According to your macro, `prod(1+2,3+4)` is expanded to `1+2*3+4` which equals to `11`. Use parens to fix it:

```
#define prod(x, y) ((x)*(y))
```

Answer (score 1):

With your definition of

```
#define prod(x,y) x*y
```

The line

```
printf("%d",prod(1+2,3+4));
```

becomes

```
printf("%d",1+2*3+4);
```

which will evaluate to

```
printf("%d",1+6+4);
```

yielding

```
11
```

A function evaluates things differently.  With the function

```
int prod(int x, int y) { return x*y; }
```

the call

```
printf("%d",prod(1+2,3+4));
```

will have to collapse (evaluate) the parameters before they can be passed.  This is because C is "pass by value" in it's parameter handling style.  Even pointers, which are technically references are turned into values representing the reference and those values are passed.  So the call reduces to

```
printf("%d",prod(3,7));
```

which inside the function becomes

```
return 3*7;
```

or
    return 21

There's a valueable lesson here.  **Macros don't understand the language.**  They are just text substitutions, and they will not honor types, operator precedence, or any other language element you've taken the time to learn.  Basically the macro language is a different-than-C language, and a much more primitive one than C.